# Set a Blackout period on Triggered Send Definition?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, marketingcloudapi

As a requirement, SFMC needs to hold the emails from being sent through triggered send definitions for a specific period of time during the day.

> For example - emails need to be in the queue from 10 pm - 6 am daily and only process/send outside of this timeframe.

*Note: We are using the old school triggered sends (not the new transactional messaging API), however, open for suggestion if Blackout is possible in the new messaging API.*

- Is this available natively as a feature?
- What are the options to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [send throttling.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_throttle.htm&type=5) This should allow you to specify both the time range you want to send between as well as the volume you want to send each hour. You will need SF support to enable this for your account if you don't have it enabled already.

The transactional messaging API doesn't have this feature set (for email anyway), so it would be on your application/script to handle the queueing and to determine the appropriate time/date window in which you wanted to send.

If neither of these is sufficient, you could include a script in your email that will insert the record into a DE and then fail the send if it occurs during a blackout time. Then an automation could pick up records from the blackout window and send at an appropriate time. Granted this is not an efficient or cost-effective approach.

Comment: You will be able to provision send throttling yourself in the [October 2019 release](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2019_email_studio_features.htm&type=5).